# Scheme of the input URI is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Scheme of the input URI is not supported. Please revise the following scheme and try again: 'https'

when I'm trying to create an external data source for my blob storage I'm getting an error like this

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services):

[image]

this feature only supports `http` api,please adjust `https` to `http`.